# Count maximum consecutive occurrence of a substring in a string, using only basic string operations

Tags: c++, string

```
int longest_str(std::string str, std::string dna) {
    int longest_count = 0;
    int current_count = 0;
    std::string temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (dna.size() - str.size()); ++i) {
      if (dna.at(i) == str.at(0)) {
          
        for (int j = i; j < i + str.size(); ++j) {
          temp.push_back(dna.at(j));
        }
        if (temp.compare(str) == 0) {
          current_count++;
          temp.clear();
          i += str.size();

      
        } else if (temp.compare(str) != 0) {
          if (current_count >= longest_count) {
            longest_count = current_count;
          }
          temp.clear();
          current_count = 0;
  
        } 
      } else if (dna.at(i) != str.at(0)) {
        if (current_count >= longest_count) {
          longest_count = current_count;
        }
        continue;
      }
        
  }
    
  return longest_count;
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do here is to loop through the given DNA strand, and when I encounter the first letter of the STR, say at index i, I will append the next i + str.size() letters from the DNA strand to a temporary variable. Then, I will compare that temporary variable with the STR, and if they equal, increase the current count by 1, clear the temporary string, increase the index accordingly, and repeat the process. If the temporary string does not equal the STR, I will clear the string, update longest count up to that point, and reset current count to 0. If I encounter a character that does not equal to the first character of the STR, I will similarly update the longest count, reset current count to 0, and repeat the process.

So for example, if the given DNA is "GTATTAATTAATTAATTAGTA", and the STR is "ATTA", this function should return 4.

The function has been giving me seemingly arbitrary answers when I tested it against different inputs, so I am not really sure what's going wrong here. My speculation is that there's something wrong with the way I update the longest_count variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? What did you find?

Comment: `if (dna.at(i) == str.at(0))... else if (dna.at(i) != str.at(0)) ...` is exactly the same as `if (dna.at(i) == str.at(0)) ... else ...`, the same for `temp.compare(str)`, which would be more readable with `if (temp == str) ... else ...`

Comment: What is newest acceptable C++ standard?

Comment: What would the answer be for the case AAAAA with AA as the substring? Do the substrings need to be disjoint?

Comment: `dna.size() - str.size()` is a bug waiting to happen. What if str is larger than dna? Unsigned arithmetic render the program behavior undefined.

Comment: It would be nice to have a complete testset for that: https://godbolt.org/z/PWrccT

Comment: *using only basic string operations* -- I see these types of restrictions in a lot of questions posted here.  The quick and dirty "solution" is to use what is restricted anyway.  Once your program works with the use of the "restricted" items, then change your code to produce home-made versions of the restricted code.  This will not only speed up the development, but gives initial confidence that your basic algorithm actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you do:

```
i += str.size()
```

but you forget that your loop itself is also incrementing i, so you are actually skipping an index.

Second issue is that you might exit the loop before

```
      if (current_count >= longest_count) {
        longest_count = current_count;
      }
```

is executed, if your last match was less than the lenght of the string back (or if your last match ends exactly at the end of the string).

Here is a dirty fix of your code:

```
int longest_str(std::string str, std::string dna) {
    int longest_count = 0;
    int current_count = 0;
    std::string temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (dna.size() - str.size()); ++i) {

      if (dna.at(i) == str.at(0)) {
          
        for (int j = i; j < i + str.size(); ++j) {
          temp.push_back(dna.at(j));
        }
        
        if (temp.compare(str) == 0) {
          current_count++;
          temp.clear();
          i += (str.size()-1);
        } else if (temp.compare(str) != 0) {
          temp.clear();
          current_count = 0;
        }
        if (current_count >= longest_count) {
          longest_count = current_count;
        }
      } else if (dna.at(i) != str.at(0)) {
        if (current_count >= longest_count) {
          longest_count = current_count;
        }
        continue;
      }
        
  }
    
  return longest_count;
}
```

Other solutions might be cleaner, but hopefully you see the problems now.

Another issue that you might have missed is what happens when your string contains overlapping matches. for example:

"ATTATTAATTA"

With you code you will find the first "ATTA", but you won't find the overlapping "ATTAATTA", so you actually need to rethink your logic anyways

Since it seems you didn't fully understand this problem, let's reformulate:

When your code reads the string "ATT**ATTAATTA**" it first sees the first "ATTA" and then it goes to the index after that, which is the next "T" and checks the rest of the string. The rest of the string is "TTAATTA" which only contains a single time "ATTA" so your code returns 1, but actually there are two consecutive "ATTA" in that string

What you would need to do to get the correct answer is to try starting with every letter, so you would need to first check "ATTATTAATTA" then "TTATTAATTA" then "TATTAATTA" then "ATTAATTA" which finally gets your correct result of 2.

Honestly a good idea might be to look at the other answer in this thread and see how he did it, I made sure he looked at this problem too :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This actually fixed the issues that I was having. As for your last point, the overlapping should not be an issue since I'm only looking for individually consecutive occurrences of the given substring.

Comment: 1/2 I think you missed my last point. Try your code with the input "ATTATTAATTA" and "ATTA". Even with the fix it will return 1 instead of 2. Because after detecting the first match, you skip to the end of that match

Comment: 2/2 This means when your code looks through "ATTATTAATTA" if first sees "ATTA", then skips to the end of that string, and finds "TTAATTA". It misses completely that you could also divide the string in "ATT" and "ATTAATTA"

Comment: @AnhQuânVõ I edited the answer to explain the problem a little better. Your code even with my fixes is still NOT correct

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a cleaner implementation for your code:

```
#include <iostream>

size_t longestStr(std::string dna, std::string str)
{
    size_t temp_ans = 0, final_ans;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dna.size(); i++)
    {
        if (dna[i] == str[0])
        {
            final_ans = 0;
            while (dna.substr(i, str.size()) == str)
            {
                if (++final_ans > ans)
                {
                    ans++;
                }
                i += str.size();
            }
            i -= (str.size() * final_ans);
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << longestStr("GTATTAATTAATTAATTAGTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGTA", "ATTA");
}
```

### Output:

```
6
```

No need of `temp`.

Also you should preferably use `size_t` instead of `int` because `max size of a string > int`.

Comment: "because max size of a string > int" Now that has me thinking. Is that always true? I *think* std::size_t must be at least as wide as `int`. But not entirely certain. Either way your advice stands.

Comment: `size_t` means `unsigned long long int`, so yes `size_t` is at least as wide as `int`. But still `size_t` can store larger numbers than `int`.

Comment: @SolvedGames no, `size_t` usually is `unsigned long int`, which means at least 4 bytes. `unsigned long long int` has at least 8 bytes.

Comment: Though human DNA can contain as much as 3,054,815,472 base pairs, I doubt that this will ever be processed as a single string.

Comment: `size_t` is `unsigned long long int` for Win64 and `unsigned long int` for Win32.

Comment: your code doesn't work for "ATTATTAATTA", "ATTA" it returns 1, should return 2

Comment: @jeekiii Thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the code and it works well now.

Comment: Not a proper fix. Still broken for "AAABAAABAAAAAABAAA", "AAABAAA" should be 2, returns 1. Don't use constants in code like that

Comment: @jeekiii Hmm, what about now?

Comment: Not only is it still broken, it now infinite loops with short strings to test. ex: "AA", "A"

Comment: @jeekiii Actually I wrote the comment before doing the changes. I've done the changes now.

Comment: Looks better! I think you should rename your variables though. final_ans and ans are confusing and it's not obvious which one is the current one and which one is the max one. But well played, this is actually correct and I intuitively would have made a mistaken suggestion!

Comment: @AnhQuânVõ Welcome :). Just so you know, you can mark answers as accepted for others to know that your question has been resolved.